# Use lodash or some other library to throttle a default click event listener on html tag

Tags: javascript, lodash, throttling

My intent is to throttle the click listener on some links and form submit buttons. The main idea was something like:

```html
<a href="#" class="throttled-click">Click</a>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    tags = document.findElementsByClassName("throttled-click");
    for (let tag of tags) {
      tag.onclick = _.throttle(tag.click, 1000, { 'trailing': false });
      // Clearly doesn't work
    }
  }
</script>
```

The code above doesn't really work since no matter what I do, the default click event listener won't get throttled. If I pass in some other function (e.g. `console.log("Throttled")`), it will be throttled but the default click event listener won't.

Other than attempting to write my own throttling function, I'm out of ideas.
Note that I'm not a js dev so I may be missing something obvious.

EDIT: The goal of throttling the default click event listener is to prevent users from submitting too many forms when something hangs. Granted, form submissions usually entail a redirection which implicates that it's enough to simply disable the HTML click event after the first click.

My idea was to implement a throttle for cases when the page won't refresh or some edge case occurs where the request never reaches the server and the user actually has to click the submit button again.

I was able to do it with a custom implementation, I don't think there's a way to do it with existing standard libraries which I find kind of strange.

Comment: Would it be: `tag.onclick = _.throttle(tag.onclick, 1000, { 'trailing': false });`

Comment: You can't pass `tag.onclick` inside because it's some kind of `Function` and not `(args) => any` type. First apparently isn't or shouldn't be callable. Anyway lodash won't accept it.

Comment: It kinda doesn't make sense to throttle the click event itself. That would be like taking away the users mouse. As long as you listen to the event, the event will be raised. Normally you pass a function to the onclick listener, like "what happens when you click". This function then can be throttled, but not the click event itself. Maybe there is more to the story, why would you won't to throttle the click event ? Also ... it think it should be `tag.onclick =` and not `tags.onclick =` , typo ?

Comment: @PascalLamers good catch on the typo.

Comment: @PascalLamers click throttling isn't anything bad, it's actually pretty standard practice in Android (you don't want to open 2 Activities just because you quickly double-clicked).

Comment: No @Spidey I totally get that - but I think what you throttle is "opening the activity" , but not the click itself. Let the user click how often and fast as he wants - but the reaction to the click ? Let's throttle it .

Comment: @PascalLamers I made some edits is that better?

Comment: I am curious about you custom implementation, what did you find out ? You could maybe answer your own question